# Legacy SDK auth'd users dont have email

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I had been using the Firebase legacy SDK to authorize users with my app.

I've switched to the new SDK, but I'm unable to see authenticated users' email in the console (https://console.firebase.google.com/project/firebase-culturecloud/authentication/users).

Is there a way to migrate the old authenticated users from having a `facebook:3903483043` UID format to the new string-only UID format and assign them an email?

I'm using the firebase-ui-auth library for Android. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is not a way for you to populate the email field for your Facebook end-users in the Firebase console.  However if you explicitly   request the `email` scope when authenticating your end-user then the email will be returned in the provider data.

Comment: Thanks for that. I guess I can still link the accounts manually.on another note,  I used the firebase-ui-auth library in a different project (using the sample provided) and that console seemed to automatically save the emails. Not sure if I modified something in my current project, but the new sdk doesn't seem to register the emails.

Comment: So, I've solved the email being null by changing the "One account per email address" setting under Auth -> Sign-in Method -> Advanced on the firebase console.

Source: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/13#issuecomment-222818397